# Animations when adding new class

Tags: html, css, animation

My web application has 2 different modes: visual and interaction. Initially app is in visual mode. When user goes into interactive mode I add class "interactive" in container div. When this mode change happens and I add this class, some new divs show up which were hidden before.

I'm using rules of this kind in my CSS:

```
.interactive #somedivThatWasHidden{
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
}
```

My question is, when this transition happens. i.e., when I say  `$(".container").addClass("interactive");` I want these new divs to show up as animations ( sliding in from sides ).

Comment: Can you show the HTML and create a jsFiddle with the divs you want to "slide"? Without that, look into CSS Transitions.

Comment: How's #somedivThatWasHidden defined in your CSS?display:none,or height:0?

Comment: currently height:0 but does it matter? I change it to display none

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQueryUI` to do animations.

Check in here..

http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/

You can also use jQuery animate function,

something like

```
$(".container").addClass("interactive").animate({
//do your things
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/